# Google one tap login popup pops even if user is signed in

Tags: angular, google-oauth, google-signin, google-identity, google-one-tap

## Angular 16

## I want to block/disable google's one tap login popup when user is already logged in.

I get login popup on whenever I refresh or save changes in code(auto reload) until I manually close it by clicking on close button.

I am using **angularx-social-login** package and login user through **GoogleSigninButtonModule** button and **SocialAuthService**.

*app.module.ts*

```
providers: [
    {
      provide: 'SocialAuthServiceConfig',
      useValue: {
        autoLogin: false,
        providers: [
          {
            id: GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
            provider: new GoogleLoginProvider(
              myclientid
            )
          }
        ]
      } as SocialAuthServiceConfig,
    }
  ]
```

*app.component.ts*

```
import { SocialAuthService, SocialUser } from '@abacritt/angularx-social-login';

@Component...
export class AppComponent{

constructor(private socialAuthService: SocialAuthService) {
  }

ngOnInit() {
   this.socialAuthService.authState.subscribe({
      next:
        (user: SocialUser) => {
          if (user != null) {
            //My Logic
          }
        },
      error:
        () => {
        }
    })
  }
}
```

*app.component.html*

```
<asl-google-signin-button size='large' class="google-button" type="standard" text="continue_with" width="400"></asl-google-signin-button>
```